# SQL: How to select unique rows with duplicate items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Our customer feeds us contracts with duplicate items.  We advertise unique products.  How could I select a distinct set of upcs with descriptions without doing many sub queries?  Horrible example:

```
/* 
eventID     int
groupID     int            // This field is different between fields
upc_ean     numeric(18,0)
description varchar(512)   // Description is slightly different but same info
size        varchar(512)   // Size is slightly different but same info
*/

select A.eventid, A.upc_ean,

       ( select top 1 description 
         from myTable B 
         where B.eventid = A.eventid and B.upc_ean = A.upc_ean) as description,

       ( select top 1 size
         from myTable B
         where B.eventid = A.eventid and B.upc_ean = A.upc_ean) as size

from ( select distinct eventid, upc_ean from myTable) A
```

Is there any way to do the same thing without sub-queries, somehow joining the two together that doesn't breed records or show duplicates using eventid and upc_ean as a PK?

Comment: Please define clearly what constitutes a unique record and provide examples of the kinds of records you receive from your customer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an ORDER BY clause if necessary to the OVER portion of the following if necessary.

### Using a CTE:

```
WITH example AS (
  SELECT a.eventid, 
         a.upc_ean,
         a.description,
         a.size,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.eventi, a.upc_ean) AS rank
    FROM YOUR_TABLE a)
SELECT x.eventid,
       x.upc_ean,
       x.description, 
       x.size
  FROM example x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

### Without the CTE:

```
SELECT x.eventid,
       x.upc_ean,
       x.description, 
       x.size
  FROM (SELECT a.eventid, 
               a.upc_ean,
               a.description,
               a.size,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.eventi, a.upc_ean) AS rank
          FROM YOUR_TABLE a) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Comment: That executes lightning fast.  The total time went from over 30 seconds to something around 4 seconds and that was after I added a bunch of stuff because the time was pretty quick.  Before that, it was under a second.  Thank you very much.  I had to add an "order by" in the over part right after "partition by" with the same fields.

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT A.eventid, A.upc_ean, MAX(description) as description, MAX(size) as size
FROM myTable
GROUP BY eventid, upc_ean
```

You should get similar results.

Comment: Nice answer.  I also found out if you put a function in the select list, it doesn't have to be part of the group by fields.  Sweet.  I added a function to gather all the UPCs for a lead UPC (comma separated list), which executed 20,000 records in 4 seconds.  Thank you!